# Removing smooth scroll from tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have smooth scroll JS to link from a menu item to an anchor further down the page.

The problem is that since I have tabs used on my page (which use #tabname) to navigate, it tries to scroll when using them as well.

Is there an easy change I can make to the JS to prevent this from working on tabs?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links
    $("a").on('click', function (event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            // Prevent default anchor click behavior
            event.preventDefault();

            // Store hash
            var hash = this.hash;

            // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
            // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 800, function () {

                // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        } // End if
    });
});
```

Comment: Better target the click element --> `$("a").on('click'` <-- targets **any** anchor tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide a way for anchor elements to opt out of the scroll behaviour, e.g. filter out anchors with a `data-no-scroll` attribute:

```
<a href="#tab1" data-no-scroll>Tab1</a>

$("a").not("[data-no-scroll]").click(function() {
    ...
});
```